# Ellipsis or not -is

Tags: ellipsis

Are these usages of "not" ellipsis or something else?

[**Source**](http://www.forbes.com/sites/danielfisher/2016/09/15/banner-ads-a-joke-but-not-in-class-action/#32f1e3c86980)
Banner Ads Are A Joke In The Real World, But( **They are** )Not In Class-Action Land.

Brad Pitt loves Marion Cotillard, ( **he does** ) not ( **love** ) Angelina Jolie.

Comment: Well, at least _these_ writers write in headlinese: because they are writing **headlines!**

Answer (score 2):

So obscure English time, "ellipsis" is singular, "ellipses" is plural. It's not a commonly used word so I wouldn't worry much about it.

Anyway to answer your question:  Technically, yes, you are right, and these are elliptical sentences.  Apparently in "formal" English you should only remove those parts of the sentence that are actually *repetitive*, and not just (the parts of the sentence that are) superfluous.

So "Brad Pitt loves Marion Cotillard, but (Brad Pitt does) not (love) Angelina Jolie" could be shortened by removing the stuff in parentheses.  However the sentence "Brat Pitt loves Marion Cotillard, not Angelina Jolie" is *not* strictly formal, since you excluded the expected conjunction "but".

However, in this day and age it's not necessary to be formal.  It's often more natural and native to write like a newspaper headline.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately if people insist on writing like a newspaper headline, in future there will be vast difference in English language actually in any language.

Comment: What's _obscure_ about the plural of _ellipsis?_ Or of _crisis?_ Or of _basis?_ Or of _analysis?_ Or of _thesis?_ (Or any of the words formed with it?) Or, for that matter, of _index, bacterium, stratum_ and _phenomenon?_ How about _crisis_ and its plural: commonly used?

Comment: @P.E.Dant is that a question or an argument?  It's obscure because that level of detail is rarely used or useful in casual conversation outside of academia. It's like the old argument over the plural of "octopus" -- the average English speaker couldn't care less. 

Interesting to know, certainly, but mostly just trivia.

Comment: It's neither: it's a comment in the form of a rhetorical interrogative. There is no "argument," old or new, over the plurals of crisis, basis, thesis, &c. &c. &c. To tell a learner that such things are obscure is to do that learner a disservice. The plural of _ellipsis_ is not "ellipsises," and that's not at all obscure.